# Google Docs - create image at bookmark with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have created a bookmark in Google Docs. I know the bookmark Id.

```
function addBookmark() {
 var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
 var cursor = doc.getCursor();
 var bookmark = doc.addBookmark(cursor);

 var bookmarkId = bookmark.getId();

 Logger.log(bookmarkId);  
}
```

1. Can I create an image from Google Drive at the bookmark?
2. After creating the image I want to update it regularly with a time-based trigger. Do I have to delete the image before or can I update it without deleting it?

Comment: What do you mean, "create an image?" Take a screenshot? Insert an image from Drive? You can accomplish the second portion several ways. Use methods in the [Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#insertinlineimagechildindex-image) class of DocumentApp.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I take an image from Drive. I created several paragraphs. I can add the image with f.e. `var childIndex = body.getNumChildren() - 1;body.insertImage(childIndex, image);` This childIndex changes when adding more paragraps. How can I find the exact childIndex for a specific paragraph? By searching a text string? How works it?

Comment: I update the image on child index 0 with `body.getChild(0).asParagraph().clear(); body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(image);` - is this the usual way to update a picture? My problem: the picture is at absolute position child index 0. When another user adds a paragraph before this position, the next picture update would append the picture to this position and not to the original paragraph. How can I get a relative child index position, depends on the paragraph text?

Comment: You could append a bookmark on the new image and stopped it in the properties of the doc to set it apart from anything else appliances by other users.

Comment: You have convinced me to work with the methods in the paragraph class - no bookmarks :) Summarized. I add a picture with child index 0. `body.getChild(0).asParagraph().clear(); body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(image);` After this, I add several paragraphs before it. The picture is at child index X, not 0 now. Yet, I will update exactly this picture. The child index is unknown. How can I find out what child index the picture has now?

Comment: Can I search for the paragraph text and then read the child id?

Comment: I found the solution. `var paragraphPosition = body.findText("paragraph_test").getElement().getParent().asParagraph();
  paragraphPosition.clear().appendText("paragraph_test");
  paragraphPosition.appendInlineImage(image);` 
My questions are answered. Thanks for the note with the paragraphs. I will write an answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bookmark Id is not helpful. Better is to write a paragraph with specific text in the document. Now you can search for it and add or update the image.

```
function updateImageAtParagraph() {
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

 // Get an image in Drive from its ID.
 var image = DriveApp.getFileById('...imageId...');

 var searchString = "paragraphText";  //specific text paragraph in the document

 var paragraphSearch = body.findText(searchString);

 if(paragraphSearch !== null) {
   var paragraph = paragraphSearch.getElement().getParent().asParagraph();
   paragraph.clear().appendText(searchString);
   paragraph.appendInlineImage(image);
 }
}
```